# NSDictionary object to NSDate

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsdate, nsdictionary

I need help about this issue.

I would convert a `NSString` object got by key from a `NSMutableDictionary` into a `NSDate`

This is the object from the dictionary

```
[elemento objectForKey:@"data"]
```

Here is the entire code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // Time format for the string value
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[elemento objectForKey:@"data"]];
NSLog(@"date => %@", date);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"date modded => %@", dateStr);
```

`
But from the console I obtain this messages:

```
2012-08-27 11:51:31.961 iRSSReader[2319:c07] date from dictionary => Thu, 03 May 2012 16:55:02 +0000

2012-08-27 11:51:31.962 iRSSReader[2319:c07] date => (null)
2012-08-27 11:51:31.962 iRSSReader[2319:c07] date modded => (null)
```

If I try with a `NSString` value, instead of `NSDictionary` value, for example

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Thu, 03 May 2012 16:55:02 +0000"
```

it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you have an NSString as an Object/Value for the key "data" in your dictionary? Also, isn't the keyword "data" a bit risky for confusion?

Comment: Hi @ff10, thanks for your reply. The "data" into the dictionary is stored like a NSMutablesString obtained by the xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

Possible **elemento** not contains key "data" -> [elemento objectForKey:@"data"] is **nil**